# Linq: no return value caused exception

Tags: c#, linq

I have this query LINQ to scrape web page

```
string temp = statusLinkList[0].Descendants()
    .Where(x => (x.Name == "a" && x.Attributes["title"].Value.Contains("Go to the first page of results.")))
    .ToList()
    .First()
    .GetAttributeValue("href", null);
```

in some cases no records are returned by the query and it causes exception. I need to set default value in this case. Most suitable is to use ".DefaultIfEmpty()". I am not able implement this to avoid exception and set default value of string temp.

```
string temp = statusLinkList[0].Descendants()
    .Where(x => (x.Name == "a" && x.Attributes["title"].Value.Contains("Go to the first page of results.")))
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
    .ToList()
    .First()
    .GetAttributeValue("href", null);
```

empty list is returned here ".ToList().First()."

I am overgoogled now. Thanks in advance for any help with this matter.

Comment: It's very unclear to me what you mean by "I am not able implement this to avoid exception and set default value od string temp."

Comment: (It's also unclear why you're creating a whole list just to get the first value. What's the point of the `ToList` call?)

Comment: If you just care about the first, don't `.ToList()` first, also try `.FirstOrDefault()?.Get...`

Comment: Use FirstOrDefault() and also wrap in try/catch to help further debug issue.  If it persists rewrite functionality in for loop to better see the pieces.

Comment: @crashmstr Thank you point me out to my stupid code. It helps me understand LINQ more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, remove the `ToList` in the query. It creates a temporary list in memory for no reason.
Second, `DefaultIfEmpty` allows to pass the fallback value in case there is no matching item filtered by the `Where`. Then `First` is safe.

```
string hrefFallback = null;

string temp = statusLinkList[0].Descendants()
    .Where(x => x.Name == "a" && x.Attributes["title"].Value.Contains("Go to the first page of results."))
    .Select(x => x.GetAttributeValue("href", hrefFallback))
    .DefaultIfEmpty(hrefFallback)
    .First();
```

Comment: Thank you very much it is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the empty list. I would go for:

```
var node statusLinkList[0].Descendants().Where(
    x => (x.Name == "a" && x.Attributes["title"].Value.Contains("Go to the first page of results."))).Single();
if (node!=null)
{
    string temp = node.GetAttributeValue("href", null);
}
```

That is provided there is only one "Go to the first page of results".

Comment: Thank you for code but I want avoid use of if statement.

Comment: @Petr Minarik: Fine. Then you should accept Tim Schmelter's answer.